# How should I organise my podcast project?

Tags: team-management, pm-software

I want to organise a podcast with some friends, with a gradual release schedule. We're about 6 people who meet up personally, but we can't get productive enough in our meetups, so we decided to use online solutions for sharing our speech's sketches and similar things, all regarding the podcast.

Until today, the only thing we have seriously tried is Google's collaborative tools, but they seem to be really distracting, and way too complex for the kind of organisation we need, which is rather simple.

What software should I use to interact with all the colaborators, including occasional guests (having in mind that not all of them are tech-savvy)?

Comment: Hi Eneko, welcome to PMSE, the Q&A site for project managers. You're likely to get a lot of generic answers for this question as it doesn't exactly fit our Q&A format. Please check out our [FAQ](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq) to get an idea of what questions are on-topic.

Comment: Try Skype, Google Docs/Spreadsheets, Google Talk, Google Sites, etc. They all serve different purposes from maintaining documentation to real time chat with collaborators. Also, check out other questions under the [pm-software](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm-software) tag, as there is a wealth of suggestions already posted on what to use to manage projects and release schedules. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the tips! I hope the question is more concise now. I'm afraid we've already tried Google software, but we failed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for putting the effort into editing as many closed questions don't get any follow up or attention by the question-asker. We appreciate the effort! I'm still not 100% sure this would be on-topic, but I'll reopen and let our community decide where it stands. Thanks again, and welcome to PMSE!

Comment: I closed this question as off-topic based on response from our community during the [site-self evaluation](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/319/project-management-self-evaluation-lets-get-critical). Again, thank you for participating in our site! Be sure to check out http://stackexchange.com to see a full list of all of the expert topics covered by our network. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

During the last couple of years (enterprise and startup) the google docs + skype was the best combination I've used and seen.

Answer (score 0):

a shared **Dropbox** (or similar service) might be an alternative. With the desktop client, is syncs between the service and each individuals computer, so everybody has all info readily available.